# How to fix 'Invalid time format for a daily job' error in Python's schedule.every() function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, time

I have a problem when running this part of the code

```
schedule.every().day.at("00:02").do(send_message_daily)
```

the problem is:

```
raise ScheduleValueError(
schedule.ScheduleValueError: Invalid time format for a daily job (valid format is HH:MM(:SS)?)
```

I tried the formula with seconds and also tried the 12-hour formula, and neither of them worked

Comment: This works for me in the newest python version - 3.10.8. What is your current python version?